# How to retrieve Server details of folder/file from applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

What is the equivalent applescript for "Server" when i see info of folder or file in MAC?

```
on run
    set selectedItem to (choose file with prompt "Select a file to read:" of type {"TEXT"})


    tell application "Finder"
        set selectedItem to (item 1 of (get selection))
        set infoList to {}
        copy ("Displayed Name: " & displayed name of selectedItem) to end of infoList
        copy ("Kind: " & kind of selectedItem) to end of infoList
        copy ("Size: " & size of selectedItem & " (" & physical size of selectedItem & ")") to end of infoList
        copy ("Created: " & creation date of selectedItem) to end of infoList
        copy ("Modified: " & modification date of selectedItem) to end of infoList
        copy ("Name & Extension: " & name of selectedItem) to end of infoList
        copy ("Locked: " & locked of selectedItem) to end of infoList
        copy ("Comments: " & comment of selectedItem) to end of infoList
        copy ("Owner: " & owner of selectedItem) to end of infoList
    end tell
    set {od, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, return}
    set infoAsString to infoList as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to od
    set the clipboard to infoAsString
    return infoAsString
end run
```

Comment: What platform is "Server" from and what exactly does it do?

Comment: @Philip "server" is information shown when we open info of a folder/file in mac.

Answer (score 1):

Additional details would be helpful, but if you're attempting to get info on a folder that exists on a mounted server volume instead of a local volume, there's no difference as far as AppleScript is concerned, at least once it's mounted. Getting it mounted might be another issue.

```
tell application "Finder" to get
    properties of folder "Macintosh HD:Volumes:Mounted Server Volume"
end tell
```

Comment: i'm attempting to get info on a folder that exists on a mounted server volume. I'm able to retrieve all details except server details. This could be helpful in retrieving IP where it is mounted. So far how i achieved to retrieve details is posted in my question.

Comment: Has there been any development on this end? I'm trying to get the same information. I have the mounted server's local name, but I need the actual server location.